# SSIS Set variable to next Monday based off date of another variable

Tags: variables, visual-studio-2015, ssis

Say I have variable @date populated with 2017-07-19, and I want variable @Monday to be the Next Monday after @date, how would I accomplish this?

Also, how complex would it be to add a sort of case statement that if @date is currently a Monday, then simply set @Monday as that date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by creating a second variable based on the first variable @date.  See below:

```
datepart("dw", @[User::date] ) == 2 ? @[User::date]: (datepart("dw", @[User::date] ) == 1? DATEADD( "dd", 1,@[User::date]) :(DATEADD("dd",9-datepart("dw",@[User::date]),@[User::date])  ))
```

After creating the second variable just use the code above as an expression.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!